# DATEADD function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

I have the following sybase code that I would like to use in Oracle:

```
(DATEADD(dd,1-DAY(c_date),c_date)
```

How could I go about in changing this code up so that it would work in Oracle?

Comment: It would be helpful to describe what this function is doing.  I'm not sure I follow what that would be outputting.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the SYBASE functions correctly, you code will return the first day of the month in `c_date`.

In Oracle we can easily achieve this with the TRUNC() function, passing a month date mask as the format:

```
trunc(c_date, 'MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(c_date + 1 - extract(day from c_date))
```